# How to remove a row in presence of values less than 2 in any of the columns in R dataframe?

Tags: r

I am new to R and this may be a very basic question.
I am working on microarray data where there are thousands of columns in a dataframe. I am trying to remove all those rows that have a value less than 2 and greater than -2 in any of the columns. Therefore, I cannot specify the column name.

How can I remove all those rows that have any value less than 2 and greater than -2 in any column. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
indices <- which(apply(DF, 1, function(row) any(abs(row) < 2)))
DF[-indices,]
```

First, you want to find the relevant rows to remove.
You can achieve that by going over each row (`apply` with 1 as the second argument) and then check if it has any values between -2 and 2 (not including them). In other words, the absolute value is less than 2. (You can ask if any of the absolute values in the row are less than 2, or if the minimum absolute one is.)
This will give you a boolean vector. Applying the `which` function to it will produce a vector of indices where the value was `TRUE`.
Now you just need to remove those rows from the data.frame (I called it `DF`).

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rowSums` to create a logical index of values less than 2

```
DF[!rowSums((DF < 2) & (DF > -2)),]
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#6   5  2 -5 -2 -2
#14  2 -4  2  5 -4
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
DF <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(-5:5, 5*20, replace = TRUE), 20, 5))
```